# "How to fix" The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have exam to make web app in MVC like some kind of news portal.

I used Entity Framework to connect with mysql database. Almost made it but I have problem with view which is refered to logout. I can register and login to site but when want to logout I got message like I wrote in title.

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Logout";
}

<hgroup>
    <h1 class="text-danger">Logged out.</h1>
    <h2 class="text-danger">This account is logged out. Please, try again later.</h2>
</hgroup>
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Can you post routing rules, view name and path, controller's actions...

Comment: I can but problem is that app is not in english :(

Comment: @Emanuele: Never edit code in questions. In this case it is just a typo, but still you should never do that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I edited just a word has no effect

Comment: @Emanuele The general consensus is that code in questions should not be changed. I just wanted to point that out. Even little changes can fix the issue at hand. You are breaking a reproduction scenario then.

Comment: @PatrickHofman There are different opinions about that: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code and linked posts. In this case I thought to "Improve posts by editing or commenting": I haven't change the code (logic or intent), just a label and I'm sure about it in that specific language. Thanks for the suggestion but we are ot

Comment: @MatejOsijek can you try to explain more? Have you got a more detailed error?

Comment: can u give me your mail its kinda complicated